# Turned down a job offer a few months ago and I hit them up. What's a good reason to tell them why I turned down their offer?

Tags: interviewing, communication, job-search

I wasn't expecting they would actually be replying to me when I wanted to re-apply. Now they're asking why I turned down their job offer and why I want to reapply.

I told them before that I turned it down because I had a better offer. And I'm reapplying because the job now turns out I didn't like it that much. Would that be okay to say and it wouldn't be a red flag?

Answer (score 4):

Tell them "I got an offer from another company that promised a lot more than you did. Unfortunately, there was a huge difference between what the promised and the reality when I started".

Everyone will (or should) understand that you go for the better offer. And everyone knows that promises are sometimes not fulfilled. Plus you tell them implicitely that you think their company is trustworthy.

Comment: "there was a huge difference between what the promised and the reality when I started" what did you mean by this? the promised pay? or the promised type of work? Cause in reality, i just didnt really like the type of work i do here.

Comment: @itsmaluma, you didn't ask about what the truth is - you know that better than I do. You asked about what to tell the other company.

Comment: @itsmaluma, would you have taken that other job if you knew beforehand what type of work you would be doing? Each job offer contains an (implied) promise for the type of work you will be doing.

Comment: “Cause in reality, i just didnt really like the type of work i do here.” - There is no way to sugar coat that after only a couple months.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau i wouldnt have taken the job if it was discussed. they added jobs for me that isnt even suitable for my skillset

Answer (score 3):

> Would that be okay to say and it wouldn't be a red flag?

Not if you actually want the job. It's basically saying they're second choice and you only last a few months anyway.

Comment: I know thats my concern. So whats a better thing to say? I was planning on saying this is a freelance contract and not a regular one cause they know im a freelancer before this. It sounds less worse cause in freelance, you can just leave any time. Or at least my contract is already over and i didnt extend it.

Comment: That just says you turned down a permanent position for a few months freelancing. Next freelancing job comes up, you'll probably dissappear.

Comment: Well lol so what the hell do i say to them then do i just not reply and not even try HAHAHHA

Comment: Just say your circumstances have changed and now their job is a much better one for you. You keep these sorts of things brief and try and gloss them over if possible. If they push the point then they're just stringing you along for amusement with little or no intention of employing you.

Comment: Oh right. I dont owe them a specific reason. I could just explain vaguely.

Comment: “I was planning on saying this is a freelance contract and not a regular one cause they know im a freelancer before this.” - So you are going to lie?  If you applied to their any of their competitors, that’s easy to confirm, and then you will be labeled as a lier. **Don’t lie**

Comment: @Donald yes definitely i will not do that. honestly im thinking too much about this. if they dont hire me, then its just not meant to be